# Is there a way to save password to the browser with Flash sites?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a way to prompt the browser to save a password on a Flex or Flash app? And on returning to a webpage retrieving that login (the same behavior as HTML sites have)? I'm open to creative solutions...

~~~ **UPDATE** ~~~~~~~~~~~~

I should have mentioned I'm trying to avoid the SharedObject route. This is because of features like FireFox' and Chromes' sync feature which makes logins and cookies portable across devices. I'm thinking about copying username and password to HTML text inputs and checking for their existence on HTML page load. What do you think?

Comment: One of my apps uses a Shared Object w/ encrypted user data.  If shared object exists; try to validate the user against that data immediately.  My preference would be not to save passwords--even encrypted--in a shared object; so ideally you can have a way to validate a user based on some piece of data (Such as a UserID?) separate from their username and password.

Comment: Are you encrypting the password (MD5 hash) before writing to shared object or is the Shared Object itself encrypted itself? I know that was a newer feature in AIR but I didn't know that it's available for use in the browser (if that's what you meant).

Comment: We encrypting the password (And username) before writing it to the shared object.  I forget the specific algorithm we use; but it is an encryption form that can be decrypted.  That choice was against my recommendation; but I got outvoted.

Comment: I understand. And it's true there's a balance between building Fort Knox and using a bike lock. I think with digital information I think it's better to err on the safer side but unfortunately, that's happened to me too.

Answer (score 1):

No "creative" solutions required. Just use a local [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).

Write `userData` to disk:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("my_user_data", "/", false);
so.data.user = userData;
so.flush(90000);
so.close();
```

Read `userData` from disk:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("my_user_data", "/", false);
var userData:UserData;

if (so.data.hasOwnProperty('user'))
    userData = so.data.user as UserData;
```

Now fill the TextInputs with the contents of `userData`

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Yeah, that's quite a relevant piece of information. Nevertheless it makes this an interesting question. Another use case to consider is a plugin like LastPass that fills in the data or even logs in automatically.